# A word with meaning smoothly connecting two known things

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say we have two facts known:

> Fact A: When there is no cat, there are 10 mice.
>
> Fact B: When there is 10 cats, there is no mouse.

Suppose now I got a new result:

> New result: When there is *n* cats, then there are 10 - *n* mice.

So this new result generalizes the two known facts.

My question is: Is there any verb to describe that the new result does nicely connect the two known facts smoothly, like "The new result 'verb' the Fact A and the Fact B"?

It's like the so-called "polynomial interpolation", I mean drawing a continuous line between two known points, but somehow the word "interpolate" has no such "connection" meaning.

Comment: That equation ***fits*** the data.

Comment: @Jim Sure I can say the new result fits the two known facts. But I want to describe more on how it fits them, in a way that it smoothly connects the two known results.

Comment: You might want to check the mathematics site, if you're after the correct jargon.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I'm not asking for a jargon, I just want to use this word in some introductory text. So it would be good if there is some non-jargon which suits the meaning.

Comment: @Salomo - Can we say that the new result "*gives light to*" (or "*sheds light on*") Fact A and Fact B? Would that help?

Comment: @Justin I think "give light to" is not better because it has no meaning of "connecting."

Comment: Conjoins, relates, couples?

Answer (score 1):

You already have it. The equation *generalizes* the earlier data. If you are concerned specifically with the mathematical quality of smoothness, it is a property of your generalized model. You chose a smooth, well behaved expression as a generalization. You may also be trying to get at the *exactness* of the fit (a yes/no proposition) or the *goodness* of a fit (graded with a formal metric such as least squares method). But these aren't matters of smoothness. The idea of smoothness doesn't connect a model to it's data sample.

> Generalization is the process of identifying the parts of a whole, as belonging to the whole. The parts, completely unrelated may be brought together as a group, belonging to the whole by establishing a common relation between them.

Wikipedia: generalization - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization

> In the second chapter of the Springer book Advanced Mathematical Thinking, Tommy Dreyfus defines generalization as the derivation or induction from something particular to something general by looking at the common things and expanding their domains of validity.
>
> Posted on August 21, 2016 by Mohammed Kaabar

American Mathematical Society blog - https://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2016/08/21/role-generalization-advanced-mathematical-thinking/

If the main idea is to expand the domain for which you can model and predict results, use *generalize*. If the main idea is to point out a construct that allows a set of happenings to be understood as separate instances of a single phenomenon, then the process is called *abstraction.*

> 5 : to consider apart from application to or association with a particular instance

Merriam Webster: Abstract - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstract

With the cats and mice, you already had the notion that there should be some smooth relationship, so use generalize because the abstraction had already been done.

Comment: That's true, but I am seeking for a word which describes the way of such generalization/extension with the meaning say connecting and gap filling.

Comment: @Salomo I was working on an edit as you wrote. I think you need to edit the question to try to better explain what you meant by smoothness. I suspect that isn't the right term. I've pointed to some alternatives in my edit above.

Comment: Let me try to explain it in a figurative sense. Imagine we have a dark plane. The two known facts are like two spots with light on them. The new result is like to shed light between the two light points. Of course, in my example it is not that smooth or continuous, but I just want a figurative description. So would there be a verb for "shedding a continuous path of light between two light spots"?

Comment: @Salomo You could say it *fills the gaps*.

Answer (score 0):

The term you may be looking for could be:-

[**Ipso facto**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ipso%20facto)

Use the term ipso facto when the very fact that something exists or occurs means that something else is true. For example, if you're born in the United States these days, ipso facto you have a Social Security number.

or

**[Deduce](https://www.google.com/search?q=deduce%20synonym&rlz=1C1CHZL_enNZ814NZ814&oq=deduce&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7086j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**

Arrive at (a fact or a conclusion) by reasoning; draw as a logical conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

[Relates](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relate?s=t) might work in the sense (Dictionary)

> to bring into or establish association, connection, or relation

The new result relates fact A and fact B.